# How to assign value to variable and print it

Tags: bash, shell-script

So far I managed to create a variable which stores the string and replaced blank with `_` and `:` with `@`

```
title=$(youtube-dl --get-title https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b1JEDvenQU)
echo  "${title}"
echo  "${title}" | sed 's/ /_/g;s/:/@/g'
```

---

```
XGBoost Part 2: Classification
XGBoost_Part_2@_Classification
```

---

I want to assign
mod_title -> `${title}" | sed 's/ /_/g;s/:/@/g'`

and use this variable to use inside a function but I am not able to assign and print it.

This is what I have tried:

```
title=$(youtube-dl --get-title https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b1JEDvenQU)
mod_title = "${title}" | sed 's/ /_/g;s/:/@/g'
echo "${mod_title}"
```

---

**error**:

```
b.sh: line 2: mod_title: command not found
```

I am new to bash scripting. So no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) is what you used for your `youtube-dl` command (`$( ... )`).  You need to use it again.  Additionally in bash you cannot have spaces around the `=` for variable assignment:

```
title=$(youtube-dl --get-title https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b1JEDvenQU)
mod_title=$(echo "$title" | sed 's/ /_/g;s/:/@/g')
echo "$mod_title"
```

You could do this in one operation though:

```
title=$(youtube-dl --get-title https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b1JEDvenQU | sed 's/ /_/g;s/:/@/g')
```

Comment: Can't accept the answer right now but will do it after 10 min. Thanks for providing the detailed answer .

Comment: `tr` for single character transliteration. `sed` is needlessly heavy for this. Or, just use `${variable//pattern/text}` twice.

Comment: @Kusalananda I will take a note of it. Thanks for pointing this out.